# SQL Anywhere if..elseif..else syntax errors

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, isql

I am trying to use if..elseif..else condition in interactive sql and executed a query but got the syntax error.

I have checked on the offical website for some pseudo code and execute the same code with some modifications but it gave the same syntax error.

official website where I found the pseudocode:-
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01031.0400/doc/html/asc1252677186261.html

Giving the following syntax error after executing.

ERROR:
Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near 'ELSEIF' on line 3
SQLCODE = -131, ODBC 3 State='42000'
line 1, Column 1

code with some modifications:-

```
SELECT 
 (IF 1=1 THEN 1
 ELSEIF 2=2 AND 3=3 THEN 1.5
 ELSE 2
 END)
```

pseudo code without modifications:-

```
SELECT (IF Price<1000 THEN 1
  ELSEIF Price >= 1000 AND Price <1500 THEN 1.5
  ELSE 2
  END)
```

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/if-statement.html is the actual link for SQL Anywhere you're looking in some middleware doc from the link you posted. You need an 'END IF' rather than end looking at the doc when using ELSEIF

Comment: I have tried using 'ENDIF' as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Instead of using if..elseif..else. I used the case conditions which solved my problem. 

`SELECT 
case 
    when 1=1 then 1
    when (2=2 and 3=3) then 1.5
    else 2 
end as T`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the [if *expression*](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/8170fd656ce2101484578af3b0843edf.html) rather than the if *statement*. The if expression does not support elseif. The solution is to use the case statement, as you found.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Graeme's answer, as I never know there are 2 different things, `if expression` and `if statement` in Sybase. However, I am not sure the answer is correct about 'The if expression does not support elseif.' Based on Sybase [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01031.0400/doc/html/asc1252677186261.html),

> The effect of the **IF-THEN-ELSEIF-THEN** expression is similar to the CASE expression.

It is more likely the difference between [`Transact-SQL statement`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315744.htm) and the `Sybase IQ IF statement`.

> In contrast to the Sybase IQ IF statement, the Transact-SQL IF statement has no THEN. The Transact-SQL version also has no ELSE IF or END IF keywords.